# I want to repeat my code x amount of time what should i do?

Tags: python

```
import time
import ctypes
for count in  (3000):
    def Mbox(title, text, style):
        return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)
Mbox('Virus detected', 'Would you like to run your anti-viruse software?',6)
```

Comment: define once and execute x amount of times. Move your function definition outside the for loop, and loop over count using only `Mbox()`. Also use `for count in range(3000)` not `in (3000)`

Comment: Probably `x` is 3000 and the code is `Mbo(....`

Comment: the given code makes no sense, why define a function in for loop and then call the function from outside?

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you.

```
import time
import ctypes


def Mbox(title, text, style):
    return ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, text, title, style)
for count in range(3000):
    print(Mbox('Virus detected', 'Would you like to run your anti-viruse software?',6))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `range(3000)`. It return a list with all numbers from 1 to 3000. The list can be used in a for statment like this: `for index in range(3000):...`